# Android Imageview fails to load

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm fetching a single image for a single person. Everything goes well but if there is no image in the database I get an exception (my app crashes). I do handle this with a else statement but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is the code:

```
private void Get_Image_From_Database(DataBaseHelper db,String query)// GET_IMAGE
{
   Bitmap bitmap=null;

    SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db1.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c != null) {
     if (c.moveToFirst()) 
     {
      do 
      {

        byte[] blob = c.getBlob(0);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // if there is a image it will render one
      } while (c.moveToNext());

     }  
     else{File imgfile=new File("/drawable/none.jpg"); //the else statement fails
     Bitmap mybitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgfile.getAbsolutePath());
     img.setImageBitmap(mybitmap);}
     }

    }
```

My goal is to (as you can see) get a image from a database if exits and if not, then display a default image.

Comment: Quick question - where is that default image? If the image is in drawable folder then just use `img.setImageResource(R.drawable.none);`

Comment: Yes I can also use that but that doesn't solve my problem. Again my else statement will fail.

Comment: What do you mean by else statement will fail? @esunic

Comment: In my method. If there is a image in the db. then the image will be displayed. If my database doesn't return a image then it goes to the else statement and my app crashes. So if there is no image in the db my app will always crash. I dont' know y. It should just get the other image which is in my drawable folder.

Comment: I tried the other approach as well.(see explanation on Aniruddha post,comment below)

Comment: You should post your logcat error.

Comment: see the comment on the other post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem!
Thanx guys especially aniruddha!!

```
 private void Get_Image_From_Database(DataBaseHelper db,String query)// GET_IMAGE
{

    SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db1.rawQuery(query, null);

        c.moveToFirst();

         if (c.isNull(0))
        { 
             img.setImageResource(R.drawable.none);
        }
         else 
         {
               byte[] blob = c.getBlob(0);
               ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
               img.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // if there is a image it will render one
         }  

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the drawable is in your resource inside of your project?

If yes, try this to get your drawable:

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.none);
img.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that image is in Drawable folder then just change your else part to

```
else
{
  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.none);
}
```

I guess `else` part is at wrong place.

**EDIT**

If you're using `try-catch` block, then you can do like this in catch block

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   img.setImageResource(R.drawable.none);
}
```

Comment: `Fails`? What is happening?

Comment: Actually it is not. (c.moveToFirst()) checks if there is a data on the first row if not then display the else.. the first if statement(if c!=null) is for the query and the query must always run... Of course I tried this approach as well but again it fails...

Comment: the image with the name `none.jpg` is present in drawable folder?

Comment: It is if I just run :img.setImageResource(R.drawable.none); it executes perfectly but within my method it fails.

Comment: Post your logcat error. Is it saying `unfortunately closed`?

Comment: I put the try-catch and toasted that to the display and it says nullpointerexception which is reasonable and which an else statement should handle? what do you think?

Comment: Did you try to know what is null?

Comment: Check my edited answer now, you can make use of `catch` block. I still  guess `else` is at wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

```
for loading images you can use universal imageLoader, it will also  hellp you to cache the images

and it has a beautiful option 

ex 
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder) 
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();


as you can see if you dont have any image to display to can display the default image
```